# LINQ: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting the following error when loading my data record into objects using LINQ. It was working before I added two extra fields `dataLevelId` and `dataLevel`. I must done something I shouldn't have because now it's not working. Can anyone spot what it is i'm doing wrong?

```
{System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)...
```

This is my code:

```
var groups = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
    .GroupBy(dr => new { ID = (int)dr["productId"] })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key.ID);

products = (
    from productGroup in groups
    let productRow = productGroup.First().First()
    select new Product()
    {
        ID = Convert.ToString((int)productRow["productId"]),
        Name = !DBNull.Value.Equals(productRow["name"]) ? (string)productRow["name"] : "",
        OutputFormats =
        (
            from formatRow in productGroup.First()
            select new OutputFormat()
            {
                ID = !DBNull.Value.Equals(formatRow["outputFormatId"]) ? Convert.ToString(formatRow["outputFormatId"]) : "",
                Name = !DBNull.Value.Equals(formatRow["outputFormat"]) ? (string)formatRow["outputFormat"] : "",
                DataLevelID = !DBNull.Value.Equals(formatRow["dataLevelId"]) ? Convert.ToString(formatRow["dataLevelId"]) : "",
                DataLevel = !DBNull.Value.Equals(formatRow["dataLevel"]) ? (string)formatRow["dataLevel"] : ""
            }
        ).ToSerializableDictionary(p => p.ID)
    }
).ToSerializableDictionary(p => p.ID);
```

And here is the data that gets returned in my data record.
[image]

And yes, OutputFormat and Product classes have only string properties (including Ids).

### Update:

What i want is to fill my `SerializableDictionary<string, Product> products`.
It should have 3 products and each product should have their corresponding outputformats.

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SerializableDictionary<string, OutputFormat> OutputFormats { get; set; }
}

public class OutputFormat
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataLevelID { get; set; }
    public string DataLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the collections in the debugger before they're converted to dictionaries and see what the duplicated values are.

Comment: So what do you want to do when you have multiple rows with the same ID? (For example, you have multiple rows with outputFormatId 4, and multiple rows with productId 150.)

Comment: @Servy You mean see what `groups` contains? My difficulty in debugging the rest is that it executes everything at once.

Comment: What does it do: '.GroupBy(dr => new { ID = (int)dr["productId"] })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key.ID);'?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've update my question but you've made me realize what i'm doing wrong... There are multiple outputformats for each product with the same ID which the dictionary cannot take. user Sampath just answered this too.

Comment: @capdragon Well, in most all cases you can just take off the `ToDictionary` call and then inspect the results in a debugger.  Part of the question is if you think you should never have duplicates, or if there is some way you simply expect to handle them (i.e. discard duplicates when you hit them).

Comment: @Servy : Thanks for the tip! I'll be using that a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a dictionary and you're trying to add an item with same key.

It's like below.

```
Dictionary.add("key1","item1")
Dictionary.add("key2","item2")
Dictionary.add("key1","item3") << not allowed.
```

Check your code and avoid that.

Comment: Thanks. this has to be it... my data changed and now there are multiple outputformats with the same ID for a single product.

Comment: Also using distinct in your LINQ will sort this issue out unless you really have to raise an exception on duplicate data and then fix it in the database.